# $(X,\prec)$ is an ordered set. Show that ${x\!\uparrow}:=\{y:x\preceq y\}$ is a filter’s basis.

Tags: general-topology, filters

If $(X,\prec)$ is an ordered set. Show that ${x\!\uparrow}:=\{y:x\preceq y\}$  is a filter’s basis.

I have tried the following:

Let $\beta=\{{x\!\uparrow} : x\in X\}$

$(i)$ $\emptyset\notin \beta$  because $\emptyset\neq {x\!\uparrow}$ for all $x\in X$.

$(ii)$ For any $x$ and $y\in X$ we have that $x\prec y$ or $y\prec x$ because $X$
 is an ordered set. In the case $x\prec y$ we get ${x\!\uparrow}\cap {y\!\uparrow}={y\!\uparrow}\in\beta$. Hence $\beta$ is a basis.

Am I ok?

Comment: Is this a totally ordered set or a partially ordered set? If it's simply a poset you cannot assert that $x < y$ or $y < x$

Answer (score 1):

(Getting this question off the Unanswered list.)

Your argument is correct if $\prec$ is a linear order. The result is false in general if $\prec$ is merely a partial order. It is true, however, if $\langle P,\prec\rangle$ is a [directed set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set): in that case by definition for each $x,y\in P$ there is a $z\in P$ such that $x\prec z$ and $y\prec z$, and therefore $\uparrow\!\!z\subseteq\uparrow\!\!x\;\cap\uparrow\!\!y$.